# Compiling an Xcode project from a network folder

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to compile an iOS project in xcode from a network folder and I get all sorts of issues, most of them about files not being found on the first build command.

Most of the time it just says it hasn't found the headers inside other headers. If I hit Build again, the previous errors go away and new ones appear. Other times it just says "xxx.h" Resource temporarily unavailable. Hitting build again, ofcourse that is available but some other header is now unavailable, and it just makes things very frustrating.

PS: I am connected to a network folder from a Windows System using SMB. Sometimes if I disconnect, and reconnect to the network folder it briefly works flawlessly for like 3 seconds, and then starts spewing off resource unavailable errors. Unfortunately my build process lasts longer than 3 seconds :|.

**UPDATE** : It seems like the cause was disk access latency. I am running an OS X Virtual Machine and connecting to my real machine's HDD. I have now moved the entire VM to an SSD drive and everything works much smoother and it seems I don't have these issues anymore, so disk access times make all the difference :).

**UPDATE 2** : For some reason I'm getting this error again. No idea what changed the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it could be referenced files that aren't copied to project folder.  I have lots of projects that are located on a server resource and as long as all the resources used by the project are included in the project it works fine.

That said, my personal choice these days is to house all of my projects in Dropbox.  Still have to be careful of forgetting to copy any added files into the project folder, but it is lots easier for me to manage working on these apps on the various machines I work from.

Comment: Well I don't want to copy them to the "project folder" since the project file is in one directory and all my sources are spread across an array of folders. I have a lot of shared source code between multiple projects and having tons of duplicates is not an option. XCode is quite able to figure out where the file is if I click in the source browser or use finder to show me where it is. The compiler is the one loosing it.

Comment: Well since that is working out so well, I would keep going the route you are going.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, trying to work with an Xcode project that resides on a network share is completely hopeless. As you say, all sorts of random errors, some of the time, but not all the time. I simply have a "special" folder on the Mac that is instead shared to the OTHER machines on my network, and anytime I want to work on an Xcode project, I copy the project over into that "local" folder (and back when done). Highly inefficient and error-prone, but in my experience the only thing that works reliably (pretty sad really!)